# BasicAuth using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication

In my setup, I've an upstream system that sends `Http` requests to my system. These Http requests contains `basicAuth` token in its header.

I'm using `Spring-boot` & an external tomcat.

How can I configure my application to check, if the username/password is correct then follow normal flow, otherwise print exception in logs?

In my application there is no UI, so I do not want to show any login page/error page. The examples I've found like one [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) are based on UI, which is not my requirement.

Also, if the solution requires to configure tomcat, like in this [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html), how can I do it without web.xml, as I'm using Springboot.

Comment: do your app just an spring core app or micro service provider like rest api?

Comment: @SSingh, right now its just a spring core app

Comment: Have you Just Tried It™? IIRC, Boot will automatically content-negotiate error conditions. "Login pages" for Basic just mean returning a 401.

Comment: Why are using an external tomacat, when you have a Spring boot app? If you don't have any UI and you only accept basicAuth token, I would assume, you don't need to check the username and password, you only check the token. I don't know if you have any session management in your system, which means you need to authenticate every request. If this is the case, is it possible to authenticate this token with your upstream system. So you send a request to the upstream system to check the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Tomcat Basic Authentication then your Application will be tied to Tomcat Web Container.

I think since your app is Spring Boot based you can use Spring Security and Enable Basic Authentication in it.

Follow this [post](http://ryanjbaxter.com/2015/01/06/securing-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/) where the Author shows how to secure using Spring Security.

Comment: So the implementation mentioned in this blog will work in tomcat as well as other web servers, like weblogic, without making any changes. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

OAUTH2 Server Config

```
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
        import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
        import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

     public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
                @Configuration
                @EnableResourceServer
                protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
                    @Override
                    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .and()
                              .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**","/api/v1/user")
                        .and()
                           .authorizeRequests()
                               .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                               .antMatchers("/api/v1/user").permitAll();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
                        resources.resourceId("sparklr").stateless(false);
                    }
                }

                @Configuration
                @EnableAuthorizationServer
                protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
                    @Autowired
                    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
                    @Autowired
                    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

                    @Override
                    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
                        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                        clients.inMemory().withClient("act_client").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").scopes("read",
                                "write", "trust");
                    }
                }
            }
```

UserDetailsService implementation

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.flasher.entity.AuthorityM;
import com.flasher.entity.User;
import com.flasher.repository.UserRepository;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Service
public class UserDetailsInfo implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
        Set<AuthorityM> authorityMs = user.getAuthorityMs();
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorityMs.stream().forEach(authorityM -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorityM.getRole()));
        });
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                authorities);

    }

}
```

Implement "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService" to initialize and return "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User" instance to do authentication by OAUTH server